# Looking for a decent implementation of a jquery drag-and-drop tree plugin

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, menu, tree, nested-sets

I've built a recursive menu using PHP and MySQL and I'm looking for a decent Jquery plugin (or tutorial) - to implement re-ordering the menu based on drag and drop. Does anyone know of any?

BTW. I can do the relevant PHP, I just need something that can send drag and drop `<li>` elements in a nested set of `<ul>`s and send ajax requests.

**P.S. I've had a little look around and there seem to be many links to plugins that don't work... not quite sure if this is my bad luck or just incompetence in looking...**

Comment: I've had a dabble doing this in the past, and got some success just using the jQuery UI draggable, droppable and sortable plugins, but it was very unpredictable and difficult to use. Give it a shot and YMMV. Good luck.

Comment: yes i think I will have to make it myself - I am im the process now - shouldn't be too fiddly...

Answer (score 0):

I like the jQuery UI Sortable plugin.  Check it out here - http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/.  I've never really nested it like a tree, though, but you can specify selectors to create a hierarchy (and I know you can create custom events to check `.children()`, `.parents()`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for something utilizing jQuery UI draggable/droppable/sortable and came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4600146/128984) linking to a plug-in, [Nested Sortable](https://github.com/mjsarfatti/nestedSortable), which from the looks of it could work nicely.  I <del>haven't</del> used it myself, but at first looks it doesn't seem to try to "over do it".

Anyway, I thought I'd pass on the find for others looking for something similar.

Update: I've used it for a few things to make life easier using a CMS we're building and it's working excellent!