# Connect jQuery UI nested sortable items

Tags: sorting, jquery-ui, nested, jquery-ui-sortable, multi-level

I'm trying to connect multiple nested items using jQuery UI's sortable.

The code is correctly selecting draggable/droppable items, but selected items cannot be nested elsewhere.

How should I allow connecting (nesting) in all weblog-sections and item-body elements?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Sortable with jQuery test</title>

<style>#myToolTip {
display: none;
}
.Mainheading {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: red;
}

.weblog {
    width: 65%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.weblog-section {
    background-color: #EEE;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item-body {
    /*background-color: #EEE;   */
}

div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px #CCC dashed;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
}

OL {
    counter-reset: item;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

LI { 
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    margin: 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    }
LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }

p {
    padding: 0px 5px;
    text-align:justify;
}

.toolbox, .toolbar:link{
    color:white;
    font-size: smaller;
    font-family: monospace;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#sortable { }
#sortable li { margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; height: 1.5em; }
html>body #sortable li { height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.2em; }
.ui-state-highlight { height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.2em; }</style>
    </head>
<body>

<ol>
    <div class="weblog">
        <div class="weblog-section">
            <li>Some blog title</li>
            <div class="item-body">
                <p>Some blog text.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="weblog-section">
            <li>Some blog title</li>
            <div class="item-body">
                <p>Some blog text.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="weblog-section">
            <li>Some blog title</li>
            <div class="item-body">
                <!--<p></p>-->

                <ol>
                    <div class="weblog-section">
                        <li>Some blog title</li>
                        <div class="item-body">
                            <p>Some blog text.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ol>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="weblog-section">
            <li>Some blog title</li>
            <div class="item-body">
                <p>Some blog text.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ol>


        <script type="text/javascript" src='scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script>

            $( function() {

                $( ".weblog-section" ).sortable({
                    connectWith: ".weblog-section",
                    items: ".item-body"
                });
                $( ".weblog-section" ).disableSelection();

                $( ".weblog" ).sortable({
                    connectWith: " > .item-body",
                    items: "> .weblog-section",
                });

                $( ".weblog" ).disableSelection();
            } );            

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

If you run the code, you would recognise what's missing. Sortable is working fine on the inner items. But It's not possible to drag a weblog-title and put it under another section.

For some reason I couldn't figure out the logic I should use to write the right jquery script.

Whatever I tried, I ended up getting parent-child errors.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are looking for is not built into jQuery UI's Sortable.

I would like to suggest for you to look at https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable, as it has been the chosen answer in [jQuery Nested Sortable - Move LI elements within all available UL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188153/jquery-nested-sortable-move-li-elements-within-all-available-uls).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Do you want to prevent the section contents from being dragged and sorted?

Comment: Sorry for my weird comment before! Paragraphs of the same section should stay siblings. But the code currently allows making them children of each other.

Comment: You should look at the isAllowed option for that:

https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable
https://github.com/mjsarfatti/nestedSortable/issues/45